# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController"

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in liblibPDRCore.a(PGDeviceStatus.o)
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

One of my lib was manually dragged into project before now I have it installed by cocoapods ,then the problem occurred. And I tried add the `MediaPlayer.framework`(although I don't need this framework before) to my project,the problem becomes this : ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, but then I added MediaPlayer.framework like this

[image: how I added]